# Faster equation typing using a GUI

Tags: equations

For me writing the equations takes so much time because I'm new to the expressions, so I am looking for a editor that allows to write equations easily without the need to type the TeX code.

I found [Equalx](http://equalx.sourceforge.net) which allows you kind of do that but it seems that it only works with `MikTeX` while I'm using `TexLive`. Is there any similar program that works with `TexLive`??

Comment: Most dedicated editors have a tool bar to help typing equations and also have shortcuts and command completion.

Comment: See also [big list - LaTeX Editors/IDEs - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EqualX doesn't require MikTeX specifically. What the footnote says is

> *Requirements. EqualX needs a TeX system to generate equations - specifically the programs `pdflatex`, `gs` and `pdftocairo`.
>   For Windows the recommended TeX distribution is MiKTeX.

Hence, the MikTeX requirement is misleading, it should also work fine with TeX Live. The fact that it also works for Linux supports this -- MikTeX only works for Windows.

---

A possible alternative: I hesitate to recommend [LyX](http://lyx.org), even though it does what you ask.

LyX isn't really an editor in the normal sense, it is a graphical interface to *some* of the features provided by LaTeX and a selection of popular packages. Files are saved in LyX's own file format, but to generate PDFs, the LyX file is converted to LaTeX code in a temporary file, and `pdflatex` (or `xelatex` or `lualatex`) is run on the `.tex` file.

LyX does make it rather easy to make documents using the features that are supported in the GUI, but when you want to do something that is not supported, it can be more tedious than in a normal LaTeX document because the GUI can be more hindrance than help.

So some people like it, some people don't. It depends on what you want to achieve, how much control you want, and how much you dislike code.